# Progress Bar on PushState

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is the code:

```
$.ajax({                        
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        xhr: function(e) {
            //Download progress         
            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                console.log(evt.lengthComputable);
              if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                //Do something with download progress
                console.log(percentComplete);
              }
            });
            return xhr;
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){

        }
    });
```

This is the function I use to retrieve my view from Codeigniter. I want to show a progress bar in the meantime while the page is loading. However when I put the XHR  in the AJAX funtion everything stops working. Does anyone have an idea how can I make it run with a progress bar.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed out a variable declaration so your code doesn't compile.

```
xhr: function () {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest(); // <<<<<<< missed this variable
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            //Do something with download progress
            console.log(percentComplete);
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
},
```

Note that if `evt.lengthComputable` is false then you cannot measure the progress of the request.

Comment: Thanks for the answer man. However; I am getting the evt.lengthComputable false. Do you have any idea what causes it to be false??

Comment: I managed to make it true but now I only get the numer 1 in the end when the load is finished. I guess progress bar is more for uploading and downloading files.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.9.3+ this method doesnt work. It will hit the event listener once and thats it. I am not sure why it does not work anymore.